# React: Changing style on a div element via setter "deletes" the div

Tags: reactjs

I have a div element that looks like an application window. I want the user to be able to press "Maximize" to maximize this window. My idea is to set the dimensions of the container-div to a variable, then changing the dimensions upon a button-press to take up the full screen.

I have tried to add this in several different ways, but all of the solutions effectively delete the contents. All that is left of the component is an empty  without any styling.

Code supplied below. The windows are also draggable which is what most of the code is about.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import {useRef, useState } from "react";
import Draggable from "./hooks/draggable";

export function AppWindow() {
  // Initial width
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(400)


  // DraggableElement function interpreted from https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-hoover-j4vpn?file=/src/index.js
  const DraggableElement = ({ dragElement, parentElement }) => {
    const dragRef = useRef(null);
    const dragRefParent = useRef(null);
    Draggable(dragRef, dragRefParent);

    return (
      <div
        ref={dragRefParent}
        className={"draggable-parent dialog"}
        style={{width: width}} // mutable width value
      >

        <div ref={dragRef} className="draggable-child">
          {dragElement}
        </div>
        {parentElement}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const MaximizeButton = (givenWidth) => {

      return (
        <button onClick={() => setWidth(givenWidth)} >MAXIMIZE</button>
      )
  }

  return (
    <DraggableElement
      dragElement={
        <div className="app-title">
          Application Title goes here
          <div className="app-topbar">
            <button onClick={() => setWidth(600)}>Maximize</button>
            <MaximizeButton givenWidth={600}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      }
      parentElement={
        <div>
          <div className="contents">
            Contents of the application here
          </div>
        </div>
      }
    ></DraggableElement>
  );
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Move `DraggableElement` & `MaximizeButton` out of `AppWindow` component. Else, a new component will be created everytime `AppWindow` renders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
const MaximizeButton = ({ givenWidth }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setWidth(givenWidth)} >MAXIMIZE</button>
  )
}
```

Components get props as object

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately, the same issue occurs with this solution. Pressing the MaximizeButton essentially "empties" the <div> of all content and styles

Comment: It's because you declare components inside component.

Comment: Sorry, I am somewhat new to React. Are you telling me that if I move the MaximizeButton component to an external component and import it, it would work? How would it then be able to access setWidth?

Comment: You have to pass `setWidth` as a prop. It's rather `DraggableElement` which is a problem. You just have to move it outside of `AppWindow`, it can be in the same file.

Comment: Gotcha - so if I make DraggableElement an external component that is imported into appWindow, appWindow should be able to manipulate its CSS with <MaximizeButton> without breaking it?

Comment: I moved DraggableElement out of the appWindow.js and it works now! Not only does it work, but the code is much, much cleaner now. Thank you for your help!